# Profile error in my openrouteservice running in docker (Ubuntu)

Tags: docker, openrouteservice

I have just installed on my Ubuntu 16.04 the OpenRouteService into the docker as described at https://github.com/GIScience/openrouteservice/wiki/Running-with-Docker
It works, but when I try to get route between two coordinates, I am get an "unable to get an appropriate route profile for RoutePreference=driving-car" message. I have checked the config file of ors and there is a correct "driving-car" profile in.
Could you suggest something else to check or help?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what was the problem at the first runs, but the cache files cause the error. When I delete the content of "elevation cache", the app runs correctly in docker.